# Вопрос по верстке, но проблема с математикой

Tags: математика

Для наглядности покажу изображение, и пару слов, т.к. словами тяжело все объяснить...
Итак, есть там два прямоугольника серого цвета граница, красный это типа дисплей, так вот при скролле "Y" нужно что при конечном скролле вниз, значение "X" тоже подымалось(скроллилось), так что синяя его граница будет на одной линии с нижней линией дисплея, когда "Y" доскроллится до низу...вот и все в принципе...Там уже есть формула, но дело в том она не доскональная...к примеру чем больше "Y" тем сильнее вверх уходит "X", и вообще потом исчезает вверх.
Спасибо всем =)[image]

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы левая панель скроллилась с _такой же_ скоростью, как и правая, но останавливалась, когда её низ попадёт в низ страницы? Или нужно, чтобы она скроллилась медленнее, и докручивалась до низа одновременно с правой?

Comment: чтобы медленее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите.

Пусть `h` — высота окна, `H1` — высота левой панели, `H2` — высока правой панели. Тогда высота, на которую может проскроллироваться левая панель, равна `S1 = H1 - h`, правая — `S2 = H2 - h`.

Если правая панель находится на скролл-смещении `Y`, она прошло долю `k = Y / S2` полного хода. Соответственно левая панель должна пройти `k * S1`, то есть, иметь смещение `Y * S1 / S2 = Y * (H1 - h) / (H2 - h)`.

Заметьте, что это вычисление имеет смысл лишь если `H1` и `H2` строго больше `h`.

Comment: Урра!!! Есть такое дело, все работает как надо! Спасибо огромное, целый день потерял в поисках ответа)   
Y * (H1 - h) / (H2 - h) - вот оно =)  
Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: @Fikret: Пожалуйста!